# Скрипт грузит процесс jQuery

Tags: jquery

При запуске этого скрипта происходи увеличевается память в диспетчере задач каждые 3 секунды примерно на 200кБ.

```
<html>
...
<script>
var flQuery=" "+".flight";
var server = "http://...";
$(document).ready(function(){
reFunc();
function reFunc(){
$('.fly').load(server+'index.php'+flQuery);
if ($('.fly').text()!=""){
...
}
window.setTimeout(reFunc,3000);
}
});
</script>
<b class="fly"></b>
```

Как то так.
Функция выполняет запрос на сайт и высвечивает информацию находящуюся в тэге с классом .flight и выводит на экран. Пробовал в начале функции ставить и $('.fly').empty() и $('.fly').remove() и нифига.

Comment: @Bool, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Я знаю, просто я писал с планшета, когда обвожу и нажимаю код, то он пишет в самом конца обведенного текста 'здесь введите код'. Как то так.

Answer (score 1):

```
var flQuery=" "+".flight";
var server = "http://...";

function reFunc(){
     $('.fly').load(server+'index.php'+flQuery); 
     if ($('.fly').text()!=""){ ... }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
      window.setTimeout(reFunc,3000);   
});
```

Comment: Спасибо)  Есть стойкое ощущение, что 3 секунды — это интервал задержки 3000, а 200кБ — размер загружаемой страницы. Посему ищите, где дублируется тег с классом '.fly'. А лучше использовать id.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Есть одно НО, при Timeout запускает функцию один раз, а при Interval опять грузит память.